# Page Editing - How to populate scope variable from url parameter?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page for **editing existing pages** by populating input forms and creating a JSON file for the page template/partial.

Essentially, it consists of: `<input ng-model="model.page_title" />` and `$http.post('edit_json_file.php', JSON.stringify(model))`

However, to edit a page I need to load its (existing) JSON first, so that I can populate those models for input forms. I'm doing that with another input:

```
<input ng-model="url_of_page_to_edit" />
```

This clearly requires the user to **manually type the URL** of existing page (to load corresponding JSON file) for its modification. **I want to change that**.

It would be better to have an *Edit* button on each page that I want to edit. After clicking the button it should redirect me to my page editor, which will load the required JSON and fill in the inputs as usual. For that I need to know which JSON to load (if the page is `/page.html`, JSON will be `page.json`). That's why I'm thinking of **passing URL as a parameter** to my page editor, for example as:

`website.com/edit_pages?url=page_to_edit`

or as

`website.com/edit_pages/page_to_edit`

Assuming I have these links, **what is the best practice to retrieve those URLs?**

I am using `ui.router` and so my config has something like this:

```
$stateProvider.
state("editPages", {
title: "Edit",
url: "/edit_pages",
templateUrl: "/partials/edit_pages.html",
controller: "editPagesCtrl"
})
```

#### I still want to edit pages by manually typing their URLs

If I need to use `$stateParams` with a link in form of `/edit_pages/page_to_edit` then how do I handle an empty case `/edit_pages/`?

If I need to pass URLs as parameters (like in PHP) in a form `/edit_pages?url=page_to_edit/` then what do I need to change in my config for this to work?

Comment: @Claies, a bit confused here. How can we solve the above using nested routes? Can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting the Page Link**

```
var url = $state.href($state.current.name, $state.params, {absolute: true})
```

This will give the absolute url of the current page. Then you can do a `$location("edit_pages?url="+url)`.

**Passing URL as Query String**

For passing in query string format (PHP format) you cause something like this:

```
.state('editPages', {
    url: "/edit_pages?url",
    ...
})
```

Then `/edit_pages?url=page_to_edit` will work as expected.

Comment: what if the URL is empty? also do I still use `$stateParams` in my controller?

Comment: Yes $stateParams is still needed in your edit page controller and the above situation will handle nulls, you will just need to keep a check in your controller. ($stateParams.url !== undefined && $stateParams.url !== null)

Comment: Works perfectly, I guess I just had to learn more about `ui.router` to pull this off by myself. I also had a shortcut of getting a url, so your first step wasn't used, but thanks anyway (I will keep that for future reference)

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: how would I go about clearing url parameter? For example I want to switch to manual editing mode and so my url needs to switch from `/edit_pages?url=some_page` to `/edit_pages` (on a click of a button). Also how to populate it from `<input>` and then a click of a button (without redirecting / reloading the page)?

Answer (score 0):

After clicking a button make use of **$state.go();**

put a mapping(if required) and depends on the input entered change the state.

```
 $state.go('editPages')
```